# Issue converting in update statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

Upon updating my data I get:

> Implicit conversion from data type `varchar` to `varbinary` is not
>   allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

The column I am updating is already `varbinary` so I am confused.

```
UPDATE [db].[dbo].[table_backup] 
SET [isDeleted] = '1'
WHERE column IN (' ', ' ', ' ')
```

Comment: What do you expect the type of `'1'` to be?

Comment: Why are you storing what looks like a boolean in a `varbinary` field? Why not a `bit` field?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the data provided it looks like you are trying to store bit / boolean data (yes / no, true/false) in the IsDeleted column.

However you currently have the IsDeleted set to a varbinary column.  Although varbinary does have it's uses it would not be recommended in your case.

The solution here would be to change the datatype to bit.

---

Alternately, get rid of your quotes:

```
UPDATE [db].[dbo].[table_backup] SET 
  [isDeleted] = 1
WHERE 
column in (' ', ' ', ' ')
```

Comment: I cannot change the data type and I agree the data type for that column should be changed due to poor design however I cannot change the data type per my lead. I know there is a way to insert values there however I do not want to insert 0x or 1x as values either. I want to do true or false, '1', or '0'.